# Android app supports zero devices?

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin

I've read all the SO questions that are related to this question, but none have helped me solve this problem.  I uploaded an early alpha, which supported about 8000+ devices, but the current version supports zero, according to Google Play.

I have only two uses-permission statements, and no uses-feature statements.  I've tried removing the uses-permission statements, but (although I get another, different warning about the billing one being absent) I still allegedly support zero devices, even without those.

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hearttech.intimacytoolbox" >

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_shortname"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NoTitle" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_shortname"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        [SNIPPED a bunch of other activities from here for length]
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'IntimacyToolboxKey'
            keyPassword 'fakepassword'
            storeFile file('/Users/dave/Dropbox/Intimacy Toolbox/android/Ancillaries/android.jks')
            storePassword 'fakepassword'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hearttech.intimacytoolbox"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 3
        versionName '0.2'

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets'] }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
        exclude module: 'stax'
        exclude module: 'stax-api'
        exclude module: 'xpp3'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava-collections:r03'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava-io:r03'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava-base:r03'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
    compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.codec:1.8'
    compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.27'
}
```

I've seen in places that duplicate libraries can cause this problem, but I haven't added anything outside of the dependency system that uses jcenter.  In the gradle log output, it lists only these libraries as having been prepared:

```
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareUkCoChrisjenxCalligraphy210Library UP-TO-DATE
```

I would appreciate any insight as to why Google Play thinks I don't support any devices. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the problem turned out to be the Apache Commons codec library.  I had imported the library using jcentral, the default repository for Android Studio.  That worked fine for the other libraries I needed, but for Apache Commons, when uploading the APK that way, Google Play APK uploader lists commons-codec-1.8.jar as a "Native Platform" for the app, which apparently makes the app incompatible with all devices.

To fix the problem, I instead downloaded the .jar file from the Apache Commons website and added it to my [project root]/app/libs directory, and removed the dependency line from gradle.build.  This fixed the problem!

Answer (score -1):

Although gradle should do this for you, try adding this in your app manifest.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this does not help, which makes sense: why would adding a more restrictive statement lead to less restrictive device applicability?