# Device supporting is Zero in play store

Tags: android, xml, gradle, android-manifest

I am publishing my application to play store but i am getting device supporting zero. I have try with many changes and i am posting the code for gradle and manifest file. Please go through the code..

Gradle File:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'XXXXXX'
            keyPassword 'XXXXXX'
            storeFile file('E:/Project/Client Resources/Keys/XXXXX')
            storePassword 'XXXXXX'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.inteXXXXXXX"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.02"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "DEBUGGABLE", "true"
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField "boolean", "DEBUGGABLE", "false"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config

        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
repositories {

    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.6'
    compile 'com.github.bmarrdev:android-DecoView-charting:v1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'
    compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.codec:1.8'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'
    // Retrofit & OkHttp
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile files('libs/DraggableGridView.jar')
}
```

and here is the manifest file for the code..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.inteXXXXXX">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".utils.InteXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <activity
            android:name=".common.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".common.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" />
        <activity
            android:name=".caregiver.controller.viewcontroller.activity.CaregiverTaskBoardActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".caregiver.controller.viewcontroller.activity.PatientListActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".caregiver.controller.viewcontroller.activity.MenuActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".caregiver.controller.viewcontroller.activity.MedicationEditActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".caregiver.controller.viewcontroller.fragments.ObservationFragment"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".caregiver.controller.viewcontroller.fragments.VillageFragment"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".caregiver.controller.viewcontroller.activity.InfoActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="e84ec6e6521086a73a9e544c96270b1d78962e10" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Please help, as I am trying from hours regarding this issue.

Comment: Check out the answer to the question here [Android app supports zero devices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32432037/android-app-supports-zero-devices) since you are also using `org.apache.commons.codec`

Comment: You are a life saver :) I would have never expected that :)